# Android RelativeLayout align concern

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I'm playing with android layouts and trying to make a simple QA test, but I can't get the layout right. I just have no idea how to align those things and after few hours of fight I need little help.

Here is what I want:

[image]

And what I get:

[image]

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/nodeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textQuestion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioAnswersGroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </RadioGroup>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/questionsNavigationGroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonPreviousQuestion"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/fancy_button"
                    android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="onPreviousQuestionButtonClick"
                    android:shadowColor="#fff"
                    android:shadowRadius="3"
                    android:text="Back"
                    android:textColor="#432f11"
                    android:textSize="24dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonNextQuestion"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/fancy_button"
                    android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="onNextQuestionButtonClick"
                    android:shadowColor="#fff"
                    android:shadowRadius="3"
                    android:text="Next"
                    android:textColor="#432f11"
                    android:textSize="24dp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answers and buttons should be always on bottom, and question should be always on top. But when text is long, the view should stretch inside scroll view.

### EDIT:

I found the way without relative layout. I don't know if this is a bug or feature but this layout scales like I want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textQuestion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomStuff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioAnswersGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </RadioGroup>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/questionsNavigationGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonPreviousQuestion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonNextQuestion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hello, which tool did you use for creating this screen layout ? [http://i.stack.imgur.com/32wzH.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/32wzH.png)

Comment: you have taken scrollview for whole layout..why don't you just wrap textview only inside scrollview..so the text of question only become scrollable <scrollView>..<textView/>..</scrollView>

Comment: I just used Paint.NET to draw the image.
And why I don't use ScrollView just for text is because I want the question to take the whole space if it's so long to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use this:

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true" >
```

Answer (score 1):

add this row to your TextView element:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/radioAnswersGroup"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="TextView" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<RadioGroup android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/spinner1" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radio0" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" android:checked="true" />
    <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radio1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
    <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radio2" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
    <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radio3" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
</RadioGroup>

<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Button" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:text="Button" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try giving the `LinearLayout` below the `TextView` an id such as `android:id="@+id/bottomhalf"` and also define `android:layout_below="@+id/textQuestion"`

Then to your `TextView` add `android:layout_above="@+id/bottomhalf"`

Answer (score 0):

I think the following changes will solve the problem,

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true" >
```

instead of,

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >
```

I hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Use the folowing layout, it produces output as you mentioned in 1st link. Modify for spacing and drawables. I hope it will help you.

I used 800X480 resolution in portrait mode to check output, you have to modify layout width and height according to your device resolution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300px"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textQuestion"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </ScrollView>
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioAnswersGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio0" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" android:checked="true" />
        <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />
        <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio2" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />
        <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio3" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />               
    </RadioGroup>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/questionsNavigationGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPreviousQuestion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:onClick="onPreviousQuestionButtonClick"
            android:shadowColor="#fff"
            android:shadowRadius="3"
            android:text="Back"
            android:textColor="#432f11"
            android:textSize="24dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonNextQuestion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"                    
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:onClick="onNextQuestionButtonClick"
            android:shadowColor="#fff"
            android:shadowRadius="3"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textColor="#432f11"
            android:textSize="24dp" />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way without relative layout. I don't know if this is a bug or feature but this layout scales like I want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textQuestion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomStuff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioAnswersGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </RadioGroup>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/questionsNavigationGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonPreviousQuestion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonNextQuestion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have been working on a similar project having the some similar requirement of yours.
I have both spinner, buttons imageviews etc on a pane

Please check the below xml layout code and try changing few of its parameters to adjust it accordingly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="3sp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/innerRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgStartStop"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/startstop"
                android:onClick="startstop"
                android:src="@drawable/start" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnStatus"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgStartStop"
                android:onClick="showStatus"
                android:text="@string/ontime" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgPushToTalk"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/imgStartStop"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/pushtotalk"
                android:onClick="activatePushtoTalk"
                android:src="@drawable/pushtotalkidle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtExpectedNumberofPassengers"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/imgPushToTalk"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/expectednumberofpassengers"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNumberofPassengers"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/imgPushToTalk"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txtExpectedNumberofPassengers"
                android:text="@string/numberofpassengers"
                android:textColor="@color/greenText"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTickerMessage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/tickermessage"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/linear1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/linear2">

    <RadioGroup android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1">
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton"
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/linear3">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```